# The tag's input on boostrap don't want to be disabled

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, input, tags, textarea, disabled-input

I use bootstrap, tags input. The tags input works nicely but the thing is, I want to disabled it, make it grey like a classic input but I can't find an easy way to do this. Do you have a solution ?
I declare my input tag like this :

`<textarea id="TagsArticle" class="tags" ></textarea>`

Adding the word `disable' or 'disable="true"` doesn't work...

Comment: `<textarea id="TagsArticle" class="tags" style="background:#CCC;" disabled ></textarea>`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't works, it is still enable...

Answer (score 1):

try

```
<textarea id="TagsArticle" class="tags" disabled></textarea>
```

Comment: try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=rsARIKGpnf. here everythings works

Comment: It works but not with the 'class="tag"' option. You can find a demo of what I am talking about here :
http://beer2code.com/themes/core-admin/pages/forms/forms.html
And I would like to have the 'add tag' section disabled

Comment: as is see, "add tag" section is located inside a div with `id="tags1399631508436_tagsinput"` generated by your JS library. it replaced `textarea` adding `style="display:none;"` to it. that's why adding `disabled` to textarea will not work. check JS library API your are using for the ways to generate the disabled version of the afore-mentioned `div`, there has to be some option for that

Comment: Ha ok, I'm gonna check that ! Thank you

Comment: Ok, I found the file, it is located in application.js. But this is a little too high level for me... Maybe someone can help me with this ?

Comment: you are welcome. Doesn't the library has an API documentation available online? also, what is the name of the library you are using?

Comment: It's the jQuery Javascript Library v1.9.1

Comment: ok, could you pls show the js code that you wrote to generate the components on the page, most importantly that div? if yes, pls paste it in the question as update

Answer (score 0):

It should be `disabled`, not `disable`

```
<textarea id="TagsArticle" class="tags" disabled></textarea>
```